# I have an issue with timepicker focus out

Tags: jquery, html, timepicker, jquery-focusout

I have made timepicker on click event of table td so user can change time with this on click of td timepicker shows and after changing time data will save with ajax and timepicker get hide and normal td show again.

In that onclick event of td timepicker shows but I can not set onchange event or onfocus out event on this timepicker

```js
$(".starttime_text").click(function(){
            $(this).css("display", "none");
            $(this).siblings(".starttime_dd").css("display", "block");
        })

        $(function () {
         $(".starttime").timepicker();
         $('.starttime').on('changeTime', function() {
    var val = $('.starttime').text($(this).val());
    console.log($(this).val());
   });
        });
```

```html
<td id="" class="td_text">
                    <span class="starttime_text" id=""><?php echo date('h:i',strtotime($['date'])) ?></span>
                    <span class="starttime_dd" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control input-small starttime" size="35" value="<?php echo date('h:i',strtotime($customer['date'])); ?>">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
                              </div>
                    </span>
                </td>
```

Can anybody help me in this...

Answer (score -2):

`define jquery cdn link $ is not defined` means that jquery is not declared.

Use their time picker cdn links with HTTP requests and it will work.